# how to render dynamic react component from server

Tags: reactjs, react-router

I have small HTML block on server which is loaded via Ajax call. It has `<Link>` tag from react router. I want to render this block so that `<Link>` tag converts to `<a>`.

I tried to create a temporary react component and pass the HTML block and render it. But the returned HTML is still has the `<Link`> tag.

Here is HTML block. `<Link>` tag is on the fourth line.

```html
    <div id="mobile-home-categories">
      <div class="row feature-categories">
        <div class="col-md-6 col-xm-6 col-sm-6 col-xs-6">
          <Link to="/bedroom-furniture.htm" state="{ catId: 3 }"> 
          <img src="{{media url="wysiwyg/furniture.png"}}" alt="furniture" />
          FURNITURE</Link>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-6 col-xm-6 col-sm-6 col-xs-6">
          <a href="decor.htm"><img src="{{media url="wysiwyg/decor.png"}}"     alt="decor" />
          DECOR</a>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
```

```js
    promise.done(function(data){
        const content = jQuery("<div/>").html(data.firstElementChild.firstElementChild.textContent).html();
        const comp = React.createClass({
          render: function() {
            return <div>{this.props.content}</div>;
          }
        });
        const renderedComponent = ReactDOM.render(<comp content={content}/>, document.createElement('div'));
    });
```

Comment: `<Link>` only works in the context of a React component, and it can't be used inside of regular HTML.  It's JSX, which needs to get converted to JavaScript (`React.createElement(Link, props, children)`) by something like Babel.

Comment: @MichaelParker yes, I was trying to render the HTML in React context. But it doesn't seem to work.